# I am trying to select all the pending invoices between the current date less 2 days and the current date plus 4 days in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

This is what I have tried so far but not working:

```
SELECT
   {invoicebase.invoicenumber}
CASE
{invoicebase.onpendinglist} = true and
{invoice.isdeleted} = false and
{invoicebase.voided} = false and
{jobbase.isdeleted} = false:
FROM 
invoicebase
WHERE 
 Date(CurrentDate(-2)) and Date(CurrentDate(+4))
end CASE
```

Comment: What [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) did did you make believe that `CurrentDate(-2)` would be valid syntax?

Comment: Is this being done in a script/ORM? If not this `{invoicebase.onpendinglist}` and this `false:` and this `end CASE`  and this `CurrentDate` are not valid. As to the date range look at [Between](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html). As example `date_column BETWEEN current_date -2 AND current_date + 4`

Comment: Sorry y'all I'm really new at Postgresql. I thought the manual said I could use math functions in a Date/Time statement. This is being used in a formula (script/ORM I think) to select invoices 2 days before the report date to 4 days after the report date. It also needs to filter out completed and delivered invoices but I figured I would tackle that problem after I got the date filter issue resolved. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You can do math operations but `CurrentDate(-2)` is not one. That is an argument of `-2` being passed to function `CurrentDate()` that does not exist.  The prudent thing to do is use the [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) command line client and work out your queries there first.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the tip. Still working on getting this correct so if anyone has an answer it will be much appreciated.

Comment: When I try to do '{invoicebase.invoicenumber} BETWEEN' I get "this part is not valid expression or does not belong to this formula". I am using Inet Designer and it says I can use basic or crystal syntax to write the formula so I'm thinking SQL statements aren't allowed in the formula. Thanks again y'all for all the help.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I should have mentioned the part about Inet Designer earlier. Thanks y'all

Comment: Add the client information to your question. This is a client issue for a client I have no knowledge of so I can be of no help here. As I recommended above use the `psql` command line, then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update. I solved this by using the `between` operator in a sql statement. But I need to put it in the correct part of the Inet Designer report software. I had to put it in the record selection formula part of Inet Designer. Thanks to all who helped and spent time on this for me.